# Trying to pull unique values using with statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I created a straight forward table, but wanted to incorporate a with operator to pull the unique 'pulses' from it. This is a label in my database. I tried the below but got an unknown error.

Error:

> 09:58:45Started executing query at Line 1 Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2,
>   Line 3 **Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type
>   int.** Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation. Total execution time: 00:00:22.736

```
with temp_table as 
    (
    SELECT distinct(b.creative_id)
    ,b.creative
    ,channel
    ,publisher
    ,strategy
    ,pulse
    ,sum(a.impressions) as cpi_imps
    ,sum(a.clicks) as cpi_clicks
    ,avg(a.cpi) as Avg_CPI
    ,max(a.cpi) as max_cpi
    FROM [digital_media].[dbo].[tableau_out_combined] as b
    LEFT JOIN  digital_media.dbo.in_encore_creative_v3 as a 
    on b.creative_id = a.creative_id
    where channel = 'Performance Display'
    and date between '2019.12.01' and '2019.12.31'
    and (b.creative_id is not null and b.creative_id <> 0)
    group by channel, publisher,strategy, b.version, b.creative_id, b.creative, pulse
    )
select distinct(pulse)
from temp_table
```

I'm certain I am using it incorrectly. Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be creating a lot of work for the database, that you ultimately discard by only selecting `distinct(pulse)`. I think you should just `select` what you need based on your `join` and `where` clause. Meaning your `sum`, `max`, `avg` and `distinct(b.creative_id)` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,(c)` or `distinct a,b,c`

Comment: Are you sure that the columns that you are comparing to integer values, like creative_id, are in fact integer columns in both tables ?.

Comment: Thank you for the notes on the distinct operator. I didn't realise this!

Answer (score 0):

I originally put this into a comment but I am certain that it is the required answer.

Either:

You are applying your `sum` to a non-numeric column which is causing problems that can only be solved through data cleaning.

Your `b.creative_id` column is not an `int` datatype and is falling foul of the implicit conversion created by your `and (b.creative_id is not null and b.creative_id <> 0)` comparison to the `int` value of `0`.  This is remedied by using `'0'` instead.

Or the total value of your `sum` is larger than the `int` datatype can handle (`2,147,483,647`).  To remedy this, convert your `int` values to `bigint` values before passing them to the `sum`, so that the `sum` returns a `bigint` data type that can hold the resulting value:

```
,sum(cast(a.impressions as bigint)) as cpi_imps
,sum(cast(a.clicks as bigint)) as cpi_clicks
```

Comment: This did the trick, the bigint conversion on the CPI has solved the problem. Thank you all.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell  For the benefit of other SO users with the same problem, please mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue.